# Populate Controls into User Control from Another User Control in Winforms C# .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core-3.1

I want to populate controls(combobox) into user control from another user control. I checked it and check that controls count in target user control already added, but somehow added controls not showing. Please help, why it not showing?

**Parent User Control**

```
ShortcutTemplate shortcutTemp = new ShortcutTemplate();
shortcutTemp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
shortcutTemp.ValuesChanged += ShortcutTemp_ValuesChanged;
shortcutTemp.Values = keyBinding.values;
keyValuesPanel.Controls.Add(shortcutTemp);
```

**Target User Control**

```
public void SetValues(List<string> values)
{
    foreach (string value in values)
    {
        ComboBox newComboBox = new ComboBox();
        newComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        newComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += NewComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        newComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode));

        List<Control> currentControls = new List<Control>();
        foreach (var control in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            currentControls.Add(control as Control);
        }
        currentControls.Insert(currentControls.Count - 2, newComboBox);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.AddRange(currentControls.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: debug and make sure `currentControls` has elements in `AddRange`?

Comment: Why are you clearing and re-adding the controls on every iteration of your loop?

Comment: @RichardDeeming i have 2 button in default, i want to add combobox before these button

Comment: @mr.x So as I said, why are you clearing and re-adding the controls on every iteration? Add the existing controls to a list *before* the `foreach` loop; insert the new controls into the list inside the loop; then clear and `AddRange` *after* the loop.

Comment: ah, you're right, the logic gets simpler. Thank you for the advice. by the way, the problem has been resolved, apparently there is another event that initializes the target user control, my bad. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem has been resolved, apparently there is another event that initializes the target user control, my bad.

Comment: apparently? how did you get it?

Comment: i have combobox for an option, each option will load different user control on one flowlayoutpanel. on common use, like i choose the option by click, will load an user control, but no default value for its component. on other part of my code, i change the option programatically, not by click, and for this action, i need to load user control with some default values for its component. So i need to unbind the event, change combobox option programatically, and bind the event again. Here some part of my code https://www.codepile.net/pile/bvYbxqn2